# Displaying Images in Image Well

Tags: image

I am a beginner trying to display an image, bitmap and tiff have been tried, in an image well or a button but with no success. The code is below. It runs but nothing is displayed. I have tried two ways of defining the string and also using self.well or _well but nothing works. If I try to use [well1 setImage:testImage]; as is shown in other examples I get an error "use of undeclared identifier.

//Code is

```
  NSString *inFilePath = @"/Documents/Track1bmp.bmp";
  NSImage *testImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:inFilePath];
   //well1 is your outlet
  [self.well1 setImage:testImage];
  [self.butt1 setImage:testImage];
  [_well2 setImage:testImage];

// Also trying this

  NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:@"/Applications/Sudoku4/Pinktiff" ofType:@"TIFF"];
  NSImage* tempImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
  [self.well1 setImage:tempImage];
```